# iPhone settings, is it possible to display an UIActionSheet after an action?

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet, settings.bundle

In the iPhone settings.bundle, is there any way to have something happen when a setting is changed, specifically I need that when a switch is turned ON, I want to display a `UIActionSheet`, I am pretty sure this is not possible, but might as well ask.

As an additional note this needs to be done using only public APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run code in the settings bundle, but you could retrieve the settings and store them elsewhere (e.g. in the Documents directory) - compare the two - and then be able to display a `UIActionSheet` (or similar) next time the application is run if the relevant setting has been changed in the interim.

That probably isn't directly what you're looking for, but I have a feeling it's the closest you will get!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, since you can't run code in the settings application.